# PowerShell Script to Ping Computers Works but Give Errors

Tags: windows, powershell

The script below works and produces output file but gives errors. I've looked at other questions and answers that addresses the same problem in a similar way but I'm still not able to figure out how to fix this problem. I've done this with a splat before but not quite sure how to make it work in this script. All help would be appreciated. Error is first and script is below that.

Error below

```
Test-Connection : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command 
again.
At C:\Temp\PowerShellScripts\PingComputers\colorfulPingMultipleComputers.ps1:6 char:37
+   if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction Silen ...
+                                     ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Connection], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand
```

Script below

```
$Output= @()
$names = Get-content C:\Temp\Computers.txt
foreach ($name in $names){
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
   $Output+= "$name, Pinging"
   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "$Name, Pinging"
  }
  else{
    $Output+= "$name, Not Pinging"
    Write-Host Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "$Name, Not Pinging"
  }
}
$Output | Out-file "C:\Temp\PingComputers.csv"
```

The script produces this output, computer names changed for privacy. So it does what I want it to do, but it still gives the errors as indicated above for each machine

```
AAA-L-CWCXRQ2, Pinging
BBB-L-DW2FQQ2, Pinging
CCC-L-JN3RM72, Pinging
DDD-L-34SQRQ2, Pinging
EEE-L-84F3ZM2, Pinging
Write-Host FFF-L-1B1CM72, Not Pinging
GGG-L-94XXRQ2, Pinging
Write-Host FFF-L-D5KXRQ2, Not Pinging
Write-Host GGG-L-75SX4Q2, Not Pinging
```

Comment: Can you add the value of `$names` after you Get-Content from that text file to the body of your question?

Comment: Since the error is specifically stating that you are passing a null value to the cmdlet during iteration, I'm not sure what suggestions could be made without having that information.

Comment: He means that we cannot see what is inside the text file and that is important as the error stems from that .

Comment: What is in the text file is a list of machines with their dns name. XXX-X-XXXXXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you have a blank line at the end of your text file. See this example.

```
$tempfile = New-TemporaryFile

@'
google.com
bing.com

'@ | Set-Content $tempfile -Encoding UTF8

Get-Content $tempfile | foreach {
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

I'd recommend just changing this line

```
$names = Get-content C:\Temp\Computers.txt
```

to

```
$names = Get-content C:\Temp\Computers.txt | Where-Object {$_}
```

which will filter out blank lines

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what the problem was. I removed the blank lines and the errors are gone